# Representing increase/decrease at glance on "opposite" labels?

Tags: gui-design, dashboard, comparison

I'm building the front-view of a marketing Ad fraud analysis tool that wants shows users how much ad fraud vs valid traffic they get.

It already does this, and the purpose is to show at a glance in a clearer, faster manner.

The issue: an increase or decrease of "fraud" and "valid" traffic will be opposite in meaning for each label. Here is an example where it gets confusing:

[image]

Notice Total, Valid and Ad Fraud rows. Users will see Valid/Total traffic increase as positive, and Fraud increase as negative. I'm concerned for clarity, has anyone dealt with this situation?

Best options seem to be:

1. Removing the increase/decrease relationships, but it seems to lose
   the ease of understanding at glance.
2. Only display the relationship for ad fraud; ad fraud analysis is the main use for our users.
3. Something else?

---

Updated:
For reference, the focus was given to the forecast comparison as the main use case.

We will be testing with a bar chart as well, in 3 cols - past, current, forecast.

[image]

Comment: I think a Month Vs. Percentage stacked bar chart would be more suitable for this problem to compare the trends of each.

Comment: One fundamental approach to comparative data change is Post-casting data.

Comment: @Ren this is a good idea, will have to try.

Comment: @Prestosaurus I'm curious to what you mean, could I ask for more details? I found no reference for "post-casting data"

Comment: @LucasToledo are 'installs' part of total traffic here? You have it as a column header on one column, but is it also the same entity being assessed throughout? Asking for clarity. You could have 'Installs' as a subheader above the table, since the table is really about change over time.

Comment: @LucasToledo, I was referring to displaying historical data. I see an example above. It’s easy and transparent.

Comment: @MikeM All values are "installs". But you bring a good point -  on a second look, the label "Installs" is out of place vs time-descriptive labels "Forecast" and "Last Month". Will have to move that elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'll admit not all your numbers make complete sense to me... the following is my interpretation of the key elements I think you are (or should be) looking for.*

The amount of *valid* traffic **is** important: rises are good; falls are bad. However, the *absolute numbers* for *total* traffic and *fraudulent* traffic are **not** that important: they obviously *combine* to give *valid* traffic, but knowing that total traffic has risen *on its own* does not tell you much *without knowing how much of that was valid*. Instead, what you should probably be interested in is the ***proportion*** of traffic that is valid: as before, rises are good; falls are bad.

Note that this gives two more-or-less independent measures: *total valid traffic* and *percent of valid traffic*. Ideally, both would rise (more valid traffic, and that is a higher percentage of the total traffic), but they can go up or down separately.

So, using your figures *as is* I get:

[image: Traffic figures]

Where the first three rows are your figures, and **Valid %** is calculated by dividing **Valid #** by **Total #** (expressed as a percentage). Because I don't have any other figures to compare things with, *for illustrative purposes only*, I have chosen to compare the *Forecast* percentage with the percentage for *Last Month*. Whether by accident or design, the figure is 64% in both cases.

For comparison, consider what would happen if both the total traffic and the fraudulent traffic were 1.000 counts higher:

[image: Traffic numbers]

Here, we can see that the *amount* of valid traffic has not changed, but when expressed *as a percentage of the total traffic*, it has got worse: 60% instead of 64%.

Conversely, if both total traffic and fraudulent traffic figures were 1.000 *lower*, we would get:

[image: Traffic figures]

Again, the amount of valid traffic has not changed, but it is now a higher percentage of the total traffic: 69% instead of 64%.

I've chosen to focus on the amount of valid traffic, and what percentage that is of total traffic, but there are alternatives. For example, you could focus on total traffic and what percentage of that is fraudulent. The key – I believe – is that you need to include something that measures traffic level in *absolute* terms and something that measures what *proportion* is valid/fraudulent.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough analysis @TripeHound , you're right on this one. I've updated the design to include Proportion as its own "metric". The only thing missing to test with our users now will be to know if they perceive this better from a "valid is going up" vs "fraud is going down" as a summary.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be decoupling color from % change and using a separate icon indicator as below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input @Omkar, its a good idea. In this case I believe it over-simplifies the progression. Given our target audience, their percentual increases will be important.